Trying to pull three variables for reporting on Notes
I have a flow that kind of works but the required Apex is not working.  I'm very new to Apex and realize this might be very piecemeal.
Basically, I am trying to get the last Note that was added to a record and then pulling the ContentVersion's VersionData of that Note into go into a single text variable called ReadableContent.  When I run the debug, I get the following error: Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details. Error ID: 39430670-68725 (-490294909)
Everything before it seems to be working correctly.
I have a Get Records element that matches the LinkedEntityId to the triggering recordId on the Content Document Link object, sorted descending by SystemModstamp.
Then another Get Records element that matches the ContentDocumentId to the ContentDocumentId on the previous element and the Filetype to SNOTE sorted descending by CreatedDate.
I would like to just input the Get_ContentVersion.VersionData in the Apex and get the converted text into the ReadableContent text variable.  Below is my code.  Any help would be appreciated:
public with sharing class ContentVersionConverter {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Convert ContentVersion to Readable String' description='Converts the binary VersionData to a readable string.')
    public static List<ReadableContentResult> convertContentVersion(List<ContentVersionInput> inputs) {
        List<ReadableContentResult> results = new List<ReadableContentResult>();

        for (ContentVersionInput input : inputs) {
            ReadableContentResult result = new ReadableContentResult();
            try {
                if (input.VersionData != null) {
                    // Convert the base64 encoded binary VersionData to a readable string
                    Blob decodedBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(input.VersionData);
                    String readableString = decodedBlob.toString();
                    result.readableContent = readableString;
                } else {
                    result.readableContent = 'No VersionData provided.';
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Handle any exceptions and provide feedback
                result.readableContent = 'Error converting content: ' + e.getMessage();
            }
            results.add(result);
        }
        return results;
    }

    // Wrapper class for input
    public class ContentVersionInput {
        @InvocableVariable(label='Version Data' description='Base64-encoded binary data of the ContentVersion' required=true)
        public String VersionData; // Input from flow: binary data in base64 format
    }

    // Wrapper class for output
    public class ReadableContentResult {
        @InvocableVariable(label='Readable Content' description='Converted readable string from the ContentVersion')
        public String readableContent; // Output to flow: converted readable string
    }
}


Please include your code as text rather than a screenshot. Text is much more accessible, and is a lot easier for people to make small corrections to (also, proper indentation is helpful).

Have you tried running your Apex on its own (via anonymous Apex through either SalesforceDX/VSCode, or through the developer console)? If there's an issue in the Apex itself, it's gonna be easier to get to the root of the issue by doing that as opposed to having it be run as part of a flow.

My gut feeling here is that your SNote may be something like a .pdf or a .docx file (somehow), which are (or can be) binary files instead of text files. Blob's .toString() only works when the data is text (utf-8). The catch(Exception e) should handle that scenario, but that about the only thing I can think of. Another possibility is that the SNote you're working on is too big. SNotes can be up to 50 MB but (synchronous) Apex only gives us 6 MB of memory to work with (meaning the actual limit on filesize that you could work with is closer to 3 MB).

Running into a governor limit (like Heap size, # of queries executed, or CPU time) is an exception that cannot be caught, and that could possibly cause Salesforce to give you a GACK like what you got.
